# Get request url from xhr object

Tags: javascript

Is there any way to extract the request url from an xhr object?
I can see the url in firebug via the channel property but you cant query this using javascript.

Comment: is this for a firefox extension or for a script on a page? If it's on the page, why wouldn't you already have that info?

Comment: I have multiple intervals requesting various data, I have some common ajaxStart & ajaxComplete events to process generic events (show/hide progress indicators) I just needed access to the url for an edge case within the ajaxComplete event.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I hope I'm understanding your problem correctly.

It should be fairly simple to wrap your XHR objects with your own object to allow for this kind of functionality.

Below is an overly simplified example:

```
// Assumption: GetXHR() returns a new XHR object, cross browser.

function HTTPGet(url, onStartCb, onCompleteCb)
{
  var xhr = GetXHR();
  // Construct your own xhr object that contains the url and the xhr object itself.
  var myXhr = { xhr: xhr, url: url };

  xhr.onreadystatechange = function()
  {
     if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200)
     {
        onCompleteCb(myXhr);
     }
  };

  xhr.open("GET", url);
  onStartCb(myXhr);
  xhr.send(null);
}
```

I haven't tested this extensively, but it should work and with some modifications (error handling, passing parameters, etc) you should probably be able to turn this example into a fully functional solution.

Comment: yeah this would be the best approach however I was hoping for a quick win without the need to refactor all the js I am currently working with. Cheers for the reply

Comment: If you could provide some of the code you're currently using, it might be possible to figure out an elegant way to add this functionality without having to significantly modify your code. It should be possible to monkey-patch the XHR objects (I haven't tested this, tho) you're returning to your callbacks (are you?).

Answer (score 37):

With the following hack no wrapper is required:

```
var xhrProto = XMLHttpRequest.prototype,
    origOpen = xhrProto.open;

xhrProto.open = function (method, url) {
    this._url = url;
    return origOpen.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

Usage:

```
var r = new XMLHttpRequest();
r.open('GET', '...', true);
alert(r._url); // opens an alert dialog with '...'
```

Comment: Quite handy.
Thanks!
I ended up with this: 
`//---Monkey Patch XMLHttpRequest-----`  

`var xhrProto    = XMLHttpRequest.prototype;`  

`var origXhrOpen = xhrProto.open;`  

`xhrProto.open = function (v, u) {`  

`    this.url = u;`  

`    this.verb = v;`  

`    return origXhrOpen.apply(this, arguments);`  

`};`  

`//---Usage---`  

`var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();`  

`xhr.open('GET', '...', true);`  

`console.log(xhr.verb+' : '+xhr.url}+' : '+xhr.responseText+' : '+xhr.statusText);`

Answer (score 32):

If you are using jQuery, you can make use of the "beforeSend" function in the AJAX request to modify the jqXHR object.  I.e.,

```
$.ajax({
...
url: "http://some/url",
beforeSend: function(jqxhr, settings) { jqxhr.requestURL = "http://some/url"; },
...
});
```

The jqXHR object passed to the various callbacks will then have that variable, `jqXHR.requestURL`, which you can access.

Comment: If you do `jqxhr.requestURL = settings.url`, you can set it up globally in an `$.ajaxSetup` call.

Answer (score 5):

According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XmlHttpRequest, you can indeed get `channel` if you have elevated privileges; however, `channel` is non-standard (might not work in other browsers), and indeed the W3C specs at http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/ do not mention `channel` nor any other way to "extract the request URL". I suspect, therefore, that there is no way to do so reasonably across browsers.

Comment: getting this information is not a problem for an extension, (as it has privileged access) but is unavailable as far as I'm aware in normal xmlhttprequest usage

Answer (score 3):

A couple of related properties that could be useful are:

---

**xhr2**

`XMLHttpRequest.responseURL` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/responseURL.

This is not supported by IE.

---

**fetch**

If you are using [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) you can use `Response.url` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/url.

This is not supported by IE.

Answer (score 0):

I also needed this because I was executing a for loop where I did URL requests.

Since usually you have the URL request before you call the open method on the XMLHttpRequest object, you can assign a random property on the xml object (in my case, the property url):

```
var xml = new XMLHttpRequest();
xml.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if ( xml.readyState == 4) {
        console.log(xml.url); // equal to originalUrl
    }
};
xml.open("GET", originalUrl, true);
xml.url = originalUrl;
xml.send();
```