# How to redirect to encrypted URL in PHP

Tags: php, curl, post, soap

Got response like `mat_4per~318310~mat_8per~482078` and I want to redirect to this encrypted URL.

SOAP REQUEST:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:web="http://com/bajajallianz/WebsalesWS.wsdl">   
    <soapenv:Header/>
        <soapenv:Body>
            <web:getVendorData>
                <param>googleCp~01/Jan/1990~M~250000~15~Y~265~10~25000~1</param>
                <pUrl_out></pUrl_out>
                <pError_out></pError_out>
            </web:getVendorData> 
        </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Response is getting from PHP CURL method. Here is response:

```
mat_4per~318310~mat_8per~482078
```

How I can redirect to this URL after got response from SOAP?

Comment: you have to decrypt the URL first.

Comment: yes i tried it but not getting any response. Also tried with online tool but it like as same. Please suggest if you have any solution

Comment: check which encryption algorithm is used , then decrypt

Comment: Don't know what encryption method they are using. We only hitting there request and we get response like this and they said it will be redirect automatically when get this url in response.

Comment: Is any method of CURL that automatically redirect to respective response?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/921198/get-request-url-from-xhr-object